# Docker-Compose MariaDB creates my volume but still uses container id volume

Tags: docker-compose, mariadb

I can't seem to get docker/Maria to use my named docker volume.  The host docker volumes directory is empty.  But, there is a new container id right next to my named volume that looks like it has all of the MariaDB parts in it.  The question is why?

My docker compose file:

> ```
> version: "3.7"
> #
> # [Volumes]
> #
> volumes:
>   data-mysql:
>
> #
> # [Services]
> #
> services:
>   mariadb:
>     volumes:
>       - data-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
>     image: linuxserver/mariadb
>     container_name: mariadb
>     environment:
>       - PUID=1000
>       - GUID=1000
>       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<snipped>
>       - TZ=Etc/UTC
>     ports:
>       - 3306:3306
>     restart: unless-stopped
> ```

I've tried moving the volume part before and after the services line with no difference.   When I do a docker-compose up, it does say it's creating the volume: mariadb_data-mysql, but when I shut down docker, there is nothing in the folder.

Thanks for any insight!
Nick

Comment: Does the volume exist before you are running compose up? `docker volume create data-mysql` creates the volume before you are up.

Comment: I've tried it a few different ways, no difference.   I tried the command suggested, volume lists, but not used.   I then tried it creating the volume mariadb_data-mysql, same thing (not used)

My docker-compose up starts out like this:

  Creating volume "mariadb_data-mysql" with default driver. 
  Creating mariadb ... done
  Attaching to mariadb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data folder for MARIADB image you are using (linuxserver/mariadb) is `/config/databases/` and not `/var/lib/mysql`. Replace this in your docker-compose.yml and it will work.

Also, the order in your docker-compose.yml does not matter: docker-compose will compile it and order everything alphabetically anyway before processing.